How to list an honorary position on a CV?
UK universities offer honorary positions, see e.g. How to get honorary academic position in UK universities? and links therein.
How does one list these positions on a CV?
For instance, suppose I am a research fellow at University A but I also am a honorary research fellow at University B.
My CV obviously lists under academic positions:

Research fellow, University A, start date – present

Where does the honorary position from University B go? How should it get listed?

To help us answer, why do you want to list this and what do you want to show? It is an honor or award? to show you work with faculty at that university?

Wolfgang's answer is reasonable to place the position in your affiliation section.
You might also consider listing the position under your honors/awards, or, its own section.
Personally, I have several "courtesy" adjunct appointments because I serve on graduate committees.
I might list this position under that section.
Just only list the position once (regardless of section), and be truthful that the position is honorary.

It's a formal position, so it goes into the same part where you list your affiliations. Just make sure that it is clear to the reader of your CV that the position is honorary -- you do not want to be accused of false advertising.

Here's how I list them in my CV:
Affiliations 
 
 Primary affiliation:
    Principal Research Scientist, [Research Institute A] 

 Honorary positions:    
    Adjunct Associate Professor, [University Y]    
    Adjunct Associate Professor, [University Z]
    Visiting Scientist, [Research Institute B]

Note to US readers: In my country, an adjunct appointment is an honourary position, usually to enhance research collaborations, not a teaching position.

As an FYI about the US, two types of adjuncts exist. The type you're talking about and the (usually) poorly treated teaching position.
